# Translation of Rig Veda by an Indian author

Tags: rig-veda, translation-request

To extend my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/translation-of-the-very-first-shloka-of-the-rig-veda), I am looking for a translation of the Rig Veda by an Indian author. A translation either in English or Hindi would do.

I found [one](https://archive.org/details/RigVedaInHindi) in Hindi by Ramgovind Trivedi, but it is not that great either.

Comment: I am surprised that it is so difficult to find. I hope someone has done it by now.

Comment: See RigVeda on [Indian Scriptures](http://www.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda).

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thanks, this seems like a much better translation than on sacred-texts

Comment: @AmitSaxena It seems they wrote translation from commentaries of  Sayana and Bhatta Bhatta Bhaskara.

Comment: Why Ram Govind Trivedi's translation is not great?

Comment: Let me know which further books you're looking for? so-that I can edit my answer to include them. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

> **Q**. I am looking for a translation of the Rig Veda by an Indian author. A translation either in English or Hindi would do.

#### Hindi Translation:

You can refer Rigveda with Hindi translation by **Gayatri Parivar** at [Literature - All world Gayatri Parivar](http://literature.awgp.org/). By [Pandit **Sri Ram Sharma Aacharya**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shriram_Sharma).

You can find Rigveda (original scanned book version) [Sanskrit-Hindi] at [here](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda) (You can **read online** or purchase the book):

> [image]

- Part 1 (A,B,C) contains Rigveda Mandala 1 and 2.
- Part 2 (A,B,C) contains Rigveda Mandala 3 to 6.
- Part 3 (A,B) contians Rigveda Mandala 7 and 8.
- Part 4 (A,B) contains Rigveda Mandala 9 and 10.

Note that the last page of Part 4-B available for reading online ends with 11<sup>th</sup> Verse of 97<sup>th</sup> Sukta of 10<sup>th</sup> Mandala. i.e further pages are missing in online reading version.

---

#### Word for word Hindi/English Translation with commentary:

Word to word translation with commentary (Sanskrit+Hindi) is available at website of [**AryaSamaj**, Jamnagar](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/), by **Dayananda Saraswati**:

[image]

- Rigveda Bhashya in 5 volumes: [Volume 1](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/rugveda/rugveda.htm), [Volume 2](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/rugveda_v2/rugveda.htm), [Volume 3](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/rugveda_v3/rugveda.htm), [Volume 4](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/rugveda_v4/rugveda.htm) and [Volume 5](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/rugveda_v5/rugveda.htm)
- [Yajurveda Bhashya](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/yajurveda/yajurveda.htm)
- [Samaveda Bhashya](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/samveda/samveda.htm)
- Atharvaveda Bhashya: [Volume 1](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/athrvaveda/atharvaveda.htm) and [Volume 2](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/atharvaveda_v2/atharvaveda.htm)

Also have a look at English translation of RigVeda at [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/RigvedaWww.aryamantavya.in).

---

#### Hindi Commentaries

Apart from Dayanada Saraswati's and Sriram Sharma Acharya's commentary and translations, I noticed another two reputed **commentaries** you may find useful:

- RigVeda **Subhodha Bhāṣya** by [Damodar Saatvalekar](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjGxfyR5N_lAhWBF3IKHXKmBqsQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FShripad_Damodar_Satwalekar&usg=AOvVaw0OJJEfn3B3Ja-Ewj-nuJXf): [Part -1](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.402388), [Part 2](https://archive.org/details/RigvedKaSubodhaBhashyaPart2SDSatwalekar1985), [Part 3](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookRigvedSubodhBhashyaHindiPart3), [Part 4](https://archive.org/details/RigvedKaSubodhaBhashyaPart4SDSatwalekar1985)
- Rigveda **Bhāṣā Bhāṣya** by Pandit Jaydeva Sharma: [Part 1](https://archive.org/details/RigvedaSamhitaPartIAryaSahityaMandirAjmer1931), [Part 2](https://archive.org/details/RigvedaSamhitaPartIIAryaSahityaMandirAjmer1931), [Part 3](https://archive.org/details/RigvedaSamhitaPartIIIAryaSahityaMandirAjmer1931), [Part 4](https://archive.org/details/RigvedaSamhitaPartIVAryaSahityaMandirAjmer1931), [Part 5](https://archive.org/details/RigvedaSamhitaPartVAryaSahityaMandirAjmer1931), [Part 6](https://archive.org/details/RigvedaSamhitaPartVAryaSahityaMandirAjmer1931), [Part 7](https://archive.org/details/RigvedaSamhitaPartVIIAryaSahityaMandirAjmer1931)

Comment: Actually, Gayatri parivar's version is hindi transalation of max-muller's english version!

Comment: Gayatri pariva's translation is inline with Sayanacharya's bhashya no relation with max-muller I observe