# What translations of Rig Veda (preferably into English) other than Griffith's are online?

Tags: rig-veda, translation-request, resource

Rig Veda is a very difficult text and it is always better to have different translations to compare.

Comment: Arya samaj... .

Comment: Related [Translation of Rig Veda by an Indian author](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12151/3500)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple translations available but i would talk about the arya samaj online vedas available with hindi and English translation. Arya samaj promotes vedas irrelevant of community and gender etc. Founder is Dayananda saraswati.

You can access vedas online [here](http://www.onlineved.com).

Answer (score 2):

“The Rigveda” by Adolf Kaegi first published in 1886;

“Vedic Hymns” by Edward Thomas;

Max Muller’s “Sacred Books of the East- Vedic Hymns part 1&2;

And for Indic version “The Heart Of The Rigveda” by Mahuli.R.Gopalacharya.