# How can I find and purchase the Vedas in original Sanskrit?

Tags: vedas

I am looking to purchase a hardcover copy of the Vedas, in original Sanskrit. Ideally I would like to get a critical text, which includes variant readings. I'm not sure what I should be googling. All I can find are English translations of excerpts from the Vedas, but I'm looking for the whole thing

Comment: Vedas are called shruti. They are meant to be learnt by listening and revising them constantly. Anything written on a book might have chance of deviating from original meaning. However I am not sure if one like that is available and let us wait for someone to answer.

Comment: Vedas can only be learnt through a guru under a bona-fide Sampradaya. It cannot be self studied.

Comment: You can find original Sanskrit text at [Vedic Reserve](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/). Also visit [Translation of Rig Veda by an Indian author](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12151/277) which lists useful Sanskrit+Hindi books.

Comment: Do u want all the Vedas or u have some particular Vedas in mind? You must be knowing that there are 4 Vedas.. and it's highly unlikely one book will cover all of them..

Comment: You can find them in Sanskrit Pdf file online.